# Baby steps Kerberos?

Tags: kerberos, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am researching Kerberos in the IBM midrange environment.

I have client server desktop application. Front end java(using JT400 api) and backend Rpgle(PCML).
So the client is using a mixture JDBC Sql and backend rpgle program calls.

My current situation is I log onto my desktop(Windows Sign on) and then have to log onto my application via my IBM i user id and password again.

I need to do a "proof of concept" single sign on where user should be able to use windows signon to use my application.

i) So I need setup a KDC server, where do I do this?
should it be where my Windows signon is validated( like my organization's Windows Active Directory is)?

ii) I understand I need Configure EIM on my IBM i( we have  3 IBM i servers in our organistion).
So do I need to do this on each machine?

iii) I understand my client code needs to change so that a pop up a sign on dialog appears anymore? What do I need to do instead?

Any help or Overview what I need to do would help. I am not asking for a detailed explanation.

Regards,
Jemrug

Comment: No idea regarding IBM i, but regarding item 1), your Windows AD DCs already *are* Kerberos KDCs.

Comment: You need to ask 1 question per post.  You'll get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look into [Jaas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/LoginConfigFile.html).  It takes care of the kerberos heavy lifting in a configuration file.  You then get a windows admin to help you get/locate a kerberos cache file and you have single sign on. As user1686 said, windows AD already has KDC.   So again talk to your windows admin team about the configuration.